Stop all running functions when Automatic logout is triggered VB.net
I am a beginner to vb.net. Mostly I get code answers from online AI websites and its been working for me so far. I am making an app which already has multiple Windows Forms. I made an automatic logout function when a certain time has passed so that it will force the user to re-login. The automatic logout function I made is working fine, but my issue is that if the automatic logout is triggered, it will not stop the running function thereby causing exception errors. I know there are ways to stop the running functions that is why I am asking what should be the best way to handle this?
The methods I tried are the cancellation token and from what I understand, you need to call this to each line of code that runs in the background.
I also tried creating a module and declaring Logout as boolean and its still not working. I am not sure what code I need to put here so that someone can advise me. Any help is appreciated.
This is one of my function.
Private Async Function UpdateTagsAsync() As Task(Of Boolean)
    Dim userEmail As String = Await GoogleApiHelper.GetCurrentUserEmailAsync()
    Dim logResultMessage As String = String.Empty
    Dim successTags As New List(Of String)()
    Dim failedTags As New List(Of String)()

    ' Determine if there are any tags to update
    Dim hasTagsToUpdate As Boolean = DataGridView2.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)().Any(Function(row) Not row.IsNewRow)

    ' Initialize and show the progress form if there are tags to update
    If hasTagsToUpdate Then
        If progressForm Is Nothing OrElse progressForm.IsDisposed Then
            progressForm = New ProgressForm()
        End If
        progressForm.Label1.Text = "Updating Tags..."
    End If

    Try
        Dim service As SheetsService = GoogleApiHelper.GetSheetsService()
        Dim updates As New List(Of ValueRange)()

        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView2.Rows
            If row.IsNewRow Then Continue For

            If isStopping Then
                MessageBox.Show("Operation stopped.", "Stopped", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                If progressForm IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not progressForm.IsDisposed Then
                    progressForm.Close()
                End If
                Return False ' Exit the function if stopping
            End If

            ' Get tag value for the current row
            Dim tag As String = row.Cells(DataGridView2Column8.Index).Value.ToString()

            ' Update ProgressForm label to indicate the current tag being processed
            progressForm.Size = New Size(200, 33)
            progressForm.Label1.Size = New Size(194, 12)
            progressForm.Show()
            Await Task.Delay(200)

            progressForm.Label1.Text = $"Updating '{tag}'. Please wait..."
            Application.DoEvents() ' Ensure UI updates before starting the update

            ' Now, start the update process
            Dim sheetName As String = GetTargetSheetForTag(tag)

            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(sheetName) Then
                failedTags.Add(tag)
                Continue For
            End If

            ' Fetch the entire range in one go
            Dim range As String = $"{sheetName}!A2:Q"
            Dim request As SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(SpreadsheetId, range)
            Dim response As ValueRange = Await request.ExecuteAsync()
            Dim values As IList(Of IList(Of Object)) = response.Values

            Dim rowIndexToUpdate As Integer = -1
            If values IsNot Nothing AndAlso values.Count > 0 Then
                For i As Integer = 0 To values.Count - 1
                    Dim rowData As IList(Of Object) = values(i)
                    If rowData.Count > 6 AndAlso rowData(6).ToString() = tag Then
                        rowIndexToUpdate = i + 2 ' Adjusting for 1-based index
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            End If

            If rowIndexToUpdate < 0 Then
                failedTags.Add(tag)
                Continue For
            End If

            ' Prepare data for updating
            Dim updateList As New List(Of ValueRange) From {
            New ValueRange() With {.Range = $"{sheetName}!D{rowIndexToUpdate}", .Values = New List(Of IList(Of Object)) From {New List(Of Object)() From {row.Cells(DataGridView2Column5.Index).Value}}},
            New ValueRange() With {.Range = $"{sheetName}!E{rowIndexToUpdate}", .Values = New List(Of IList(Of Object)) From {New List(Of Object)() From {row.Cells(DataGridView2Column6.Index).Value}}},
            New ValueRange() With {.Range = $"{sheetName}!H{rowIndexToUpdate}", .Values = New List(Of IList(Of Object)) From {New List(Of Object)() From {row.Cells(DataGridView2Column9.Index).Value}}},
            New ValueRange() With {.Range = $"{sheetName}!I{rowIndexToUpdate}", .Values = New List(Of IList(Of Object)) From {New List(Of Object)() From {row.Cells(DataGridView2Column10.Index).Value}}},
            New ValueRange() With {.Range = $"{sheetName}!J{rowIndexToUpdate}", .Values = New List(Of IList(Of Object)) From {New List(Of Object)() From {row.Cells(DataGridView2Column11.Index).Value}}},
            New ValueRange() With {.Range = $"{sheetName}!L{rowIndexToUpdate}", .Values = New List(Of IList(Of Object)) From {New List(Of Object)() From {row.Cells(DataGridView2Column13.Index).Value}}},
            New ValueRange() With {.Range = $"{sheetName}!O{rowIndexToUpdate}", .Values = New List(Of IList(Of Object)) From {New List(Of Object)() From {row.Cells(DataGridView2Column16.Index).Value}}},
            New ValueRange() With {.Range = $"{sheetName}!Q{rowIndexToUpdate}", .Values = New List(Of IList(Of Object)) From {New List(Of Object)() From {row.Cells(DataGridView2Column18.Index).Value}}}
        }

            updates.AddRange(updateList)

            ' Execute the batch update for the current tag
            Dim batchUpdateRequest As New BatchUpdateValuesRequest() With {
            .ValueInputOption = "RAW",
            .Data = updates
        }
            Dim batchUpdate As SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.BatchUpdateRequest = service.Spreadsheets.Values.BatchUpdate(batchUpdateRequest, SpreadsheetId)
            Await batchUpdate.ExecuteAsync()

            ' If the update was successful, add the tag to the success list
            successTags.Add(tag)

            ' Clear updates for next iteration
            updates.Clear()
        Next

        ' Close the progress form if it was shown
        If progressForm IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not progressForm.IsDisposed AndAlso hasTagsToUpdate Then
            progressForm.Close()
        End If

        ' [EXISTING CODE - UNCHANGED]
        ' Show results
        Dim successMessage As String = If(successTags.Count > 0, "Update Successful for " & vbCrLf & String.Join(vbCrLf, successTags), "Nothing to update.")
        Dim failureMessage As String = If(failedTags.Count > 0, "Failed to update tags: " & vbCrLf & String.Join(vbCrLf, failedTags), String.Empty)

        ' Create bullet points for success and failure messages
        Dim successBulletPoints As String = If(successTags.Count > 0,
    "Update Successful for:" & vbCrLf & String.Join(vbCrLf, successTags.Select(Function(t) "• " & t)),
    "No tags were updated")

        Dim failureBulletPoints As String = If(failedTags.Count > 0,
    "Failed to update tags:" & vbCrLf & String.Join(vbCrLf, failedTags.Select(Function(t) "• " & t)),
    String.Empty)

        ' Combine the messages with additional spacing
        Dim messageBoxText As String = successBulletPoints & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & failureBulletPoints

        ' Log each successful tag on a new row
        If successTags.Count > 0 Then
            For Each tagItem In successTags
                GoogleApiHelper.LogUpdateAction(userEmail, tagItem, "Successfully updated tag: " & tagItem, "Update Tags")
            Next
        End If

        ' Log each failed tag
        If failedTags.Count > 0 Then
            For Each failedTag In failedTags
                GoogleApiHelper.LogUpdateAction(userEmail, failedTag, "Failed to update tag: " & failedTag, "Update Tags")
            Next
        End If

        MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText, "Update Status", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

        ' Return True if there were successful updates
        Return successTags.Count > 0

    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Close the progress form if an error occurs
        If progressForm IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not progressForm.IsDisposed Then
            progressForm.Close()
        End If
        logResultMessage = "Update Error - Please add more columns"

        ' Return False to indicate failure
        Return False

    Finally
        ' Ensure logging in case of errors
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(logResultMessage) Then
            GoogleApiHelper.LogUpdateAction(userEmail, "Tags", logResultMessage, "Update Tags")
        End If
    End Try
End Function

This is my automatic logout code.
Public Sub StartLogoutTimer(interval As Double)
    If logoutTimer Is Nothing Then
        logoutTimer = New System.Timers.Timer(interval)
        AddHandler logoutTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf OnLogoutTimerElapsed
        logoutTimer.AutoReset = False ' Trigger only once
    End If
    logoutTimer.Start() ' Start the timer
End Sub

' Stops the logout timer
Public Sub StopLogoutTimer()
    If logoutTimer IsNot Nothing Then
        logoutTimer.Stop()
    End If
End Sub

' Resets the logout timer with a new interval
Public Sub ResetLogoutTimer(interval As Double)
    StopLogoutTimer()
    StartLogoutTimer(interval)
End Sub

' Called when the timer elapses
Private Sub OnLogoutTimerElapsed(sender As Object, e As Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
    ' Perform logout when the timer elapses
    PerformLogout()
End Sub

' Performs the logout
Public Sub PerformLogout()
    ' Use Invoke to ensure this runs on the UI thread
    If Application.OpenForms("HomePage") IsNot Nothing Then
        Application.OpenForms("HomePage").Invoke(Sub()
                                                     ' Define possible token file paths
                                                     Dim tokenFilePaths As String() = {
                                                     "token.json"
                                                 }
                                                     

                                                     ' Try to delete the token file from each path
                                                     For Each path In tokenFilePaths
                                                         If System.IO.File.Exists(path) Then
                                                             Try
                                                                 System.IO.File.Delete(path)
                                                             Catch ex As Exception
                                                                 MessageBox.Show("Failed to delete token file at " & path & ": " & ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                                                             End Try
                                                         End If
                                                     Next

                                                     ' Cleanup Google API service
                                                     GoogleApiHelper.Cleanup()

                                                     ' Close all open forms except for the LoginForm
                                                     For Each frm As Form In Application.OpenForms.Cast(Of Form).ToArray()
                                                         If Not TypeOf frm Is LoginForm Then
                                                             frm.Close()
                                                         End If
                                                     Next

                                                     ' Initialize and show the LoginForm
                                                     Dim loginForm As New LoginForm()
                                                     loginForm.Show()

                                                     MessageBox.Show("You have been logged out due to inactivity.", "Logout", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                                                 End Sub)
    End If
End Sub


Show an example of how your background service function looks.

I edited my post with my sample codes.
